# How to store daemon processes?

Tags: c, bash, unix, process, daemon

Imagine Docker. You can start a container in detached mode (daemon) and it will run in the background. While the first container is running in the background, you can create start a new container in detached mode and it will also run in the background. You can see the running containers with `docker ps`. This command outputs a table about the running containers etc.

I am writing a program that has the same concept as Docker (not about containers but the daemon).
Lets say that the program is `abc`, and to create a new daemon, the `start` command must me executed:

```sh
$ abc start
```

We can create a new process again with the same command:

```sh
$ abc start
```

This time, I want to list all the daemon processes (nicely formatted as a table).

Here's the desired output:

```sh
$ abc start
abc: Program is starting...
$ abc start
abc: Program is starting...
$ abc list

+---------------------+
| Name      | ID      |
|===========|=========|
| Daemon #1 | 33454   |
+---------------------+
| Daemon #2 | 42344   |
+---------------------+
```

(The formatting of the table is not important)

My question is this, how can I store the daemon processes in some kind of a container (not in the context of docker containers. an array, for instance)? One thing that came to my mind is that I can store information about daemon processes in a file, and when the user wants to list the daemon processes, the program can read from that file and display that. However, I am not sure about this approach. I cannot use an array either because it will not retain its value from execution to execution.

(By the way, the user should not execute the `ps` command. I want to include extra information about the processes, such as my program will give every daemon a unique ID.)

Comment: You can use redis. But a file also should work fine depending on the complexity and the way you plan to use this data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how can I store the daemon processes

There are as many approaches as stars in the sky. Let's say we differentiate two generic ways:

#### Decentralized

Every process is independent and separate. The handles are stored in some known static absolute location.

System services typically store pid or other data about daemons in `/var/run`. User services use `/tmp` or keep it somewhere in `~/.somewhere` or in `~/.cache/somewhere/`.

For example, `screen` multiplexer. On my system `screen` keeps sockets to running screen session at `/var/run/screens/S-username/here`. When you run `screen -list` it uses the sockets located at the constant absolute location at `/var/run/screen/S-username/there` to communicate with other screen sessions and list available screen sessions. Similar with `tmux`.

#### Centralized

Have a daemon running all the time that is responsible for collecting and keeping all the information.

For example mentioned docker. The `dockerd` daemon runs all the time on the system as a system deamon and clients do `docker something` which only sends some HTTP data via tcp or via a file socket to the master docker daemon, then the master deamon does all the work transferring state to clients so it is displayed to users. Similar with NetworkManager which uses DBus to communicate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It really helped me with my problem!